# почему в компоненте CheckBox текст налезает на галку?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

в XML оформлено так. Текст "Любой текст" налезает на галку. Как исправить?

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbQR"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Любой текст"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:background="@color/fon_color"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        />
```

Может быть проблема в темах?
Я создаю тему

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/fon_color </item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

и в манифесте ее прописываю

```
 android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

тема нужна для того, чтобы убрать панель заголовка приложения, в основном.

Comment: С такой разметкой он не должен никуда налезать , если разве что только ему не хватает места по длине для надписи .

Comment: в том то и дело, что не должен, а налезает.

Comment: Из предоставленных вами сведений нет никаких причин для такого поведения . Вставил себе в разметку ( а вдруг на самом деле раз! и налезает ) - ничего не налезает . Нужно всю разметку , может быть .

Comment: Я добился такого налезания поставив android:paddingLeft="-10dp" может у вас где-то програмно padding изменяется ?

Comment: нет, padding нигде не прописывается.

Comment: Код контейнера покажите. мб у вас у родительского слоя ширина 50 dp или типо того, вот чекбокс и не влезает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну ты можешь попробовать сделать drawablePadding.

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbQR"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Любой текст"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:background="@color/fon_color"
        android:drawablePadding="-50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        />
```

Суть в том, что у checkBox'a изначально стоит padding. Своим gravity ты, возможно, его сбиваешь. Попробуй поиграйся с drawablePadding

Comment: попробовал убрать gravity - не помогло. Решил проблему так: android:paddingLeft="30dp"